# Theme UberCart catalog page to use custom html

Tags: views, theming, ubercart

Working with Ubercart 3.x on Drupal 7.

I want to theme the /catalog/1 page, where it shows my products. I want to use completely custom html that has divs nested with tables nested with divs.

I know that I can override with my own view, but I have no idea how to get the data that the existing view is using?  I want to make my own tpl.php file that will loop the products for that catalog, but I don't know which variables to access, or what functions to call.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your theme's files will override the module's files.

You should install the "Devel" and "Theme Developer" modules.

https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer

WHen you have these installed and configured, it will show you the template names to use for specific pages/blocks/views/etc.